# Laravel 5.5. artisan command queued

Tags: queue, laravel-5.5, laravel-artisan

I installed version 5.5 and I'm trying to generate the file by command.

php artisan make: MyCommand command --queued

The error is as follows. The "-queued" option does not exist.

How to create this file in this version?

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239704/the-queued-option-does-not-exist-in-laravel-5-4

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.5, --queued option does not exist, it was deprecated since version 5.1.

Check below similar question for version 5.4

[The "--queued" option does not exist in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48239704/the-queued-option-does-not-exist-in-laravel-5-4)