# The "--queued" option does not exist in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I'm going to create Queue job for mailing. once I hit the artisan command in command prompt `php artisan make:job SendSMSMessages --queued` I got the issue as is follow.

> The "--queued" option does not exist.

I'm using Laravel 5.4

Please anyone can help me for the same. I have searched a lot but didn't found any good solutions.

Thanks

Comment: In Version 5.4, --queued was already deprecated

Answer (score 6):

The option --queued, was introduced in Laravel 5.0, and remained an option until version Laravel 5.1 https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes

Since Laravel version 5.2 onwards, --queued was deperecated as by default all newly created jobs are "queued". So your question was about version 5.4, you should create the job without the queued option as below:

```
artisan make:job SendSMSMessages
```

And here's the documentation reference for Jobs in Version 5.4 https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#creating-jobs

Comment: When you want to create a job that is not queued, add the `sync` option, e.g. `php artisan make:job SendSMSMessages --sync`.